# Is The GNU C Library an implementation of OS programming interface, or beyond that (a comprehensive C library)?

Tags: c, linux, glibc

Is [The GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/s/libc/)

- an implementation of OS programming interface or
- a comprehensive C library whose scope is bigger than OS programming interface?

According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library,
The GNU C Library  is the GNU Project's implementation of [the C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library). But it also has extensions that fall outside the C standard library.

When I start to read APUE and The Linux Programming Interface by Kerrisk, it seems to me that the header files used in the examples are from the GNU C Library. Is this correct? If yes, can the GNU C Library be considered as POSIX-compatible OS's programming interface, such as Linux's programming interface?

Does the GNU C library have a scope bigger than POSIX, for example, topics that are not normally considered part of an OS's programming interface? If yes, then I might consider the GNU C library as a  C library, because it is not just about OS programming interface. For example, are the following topics in GNU C Library considered part of an OS programming interface:

- searching and sorting,
- pattern matching,
- some advanced math functions

Thanks.

Comment: The headers you include were from whatever standard library your OS uses.

Comment: Can you specify for Linux? What standard library does Linux uses? From what library are the headers in the examples in the books APUE and The Linux Programming Interface?

Comment: probably glibc it's the most widely used on Linux systems, however which library you have is an implementation detail, not sure why you would need to know this.

Answer (score 3):

> *POSIX-compatible OS programming interface or just a C library?*

What is the difference? POSIX describes system interfaces in terms of a C library. It describes the contents of C headers, which contain function, macro and type declarations in the C language.

A POSIX platform is directly programmable from the C language as described in POSIX, and from C++ due to its very high C compatibility; for other languages, you need special bindings.

Many features of the GNU C Library are driven by POSIX conformance.  A Linux kernel alone without user space components doesn't conform to POSIX. However, many features in the GNU C library require kernel support. Without the kernel support, they either cannot be done at all or not in a POSIX-conforming way.

Comment: Thanks. Is GNU C library has a scope more than POSIX, for example, topics that are not considered part of an OS's programming interface? If yes, then I might consider the GNU C library as a  C library, because it is not just about OS programming interface.

Comment: Of course the GNU C library has a scope more than POSIX; as does the C library on just about any POSIX system. POSIX is a portability standard. glibc has some glibc-only functions in it.  Some POSIX things originated in the GNU C library. For instance, glibc supports C stdio-based string streams: you can use `fmemopen` to create a `FILE *` stream which reads from or writes to a buffer.  That has was in Glibc in the early 1990's already. It's in POSIX now too (as of 2008).

Answer (score 1):

> When I start to read APUE and The Linux Programming Interface by Kerrisk, it seems to me that the header files used in the examples are from the GNU C Library. Is this correct?

If these books have incorporated code from third-party header files, whether GNU's or somebody else's, then they should have attributed it to the appropriate source.  See what they say.  If indeed they do present third-party header code then the GNU C library is a likely source, but Linux distributions can provide different C libraries, and some do.

> Is The GNU C Library an implementation of the POSIX-compatible OS programming interface or just a C library?

It seems to me that the GNU C library's own documentation would be a better source of information than Wikipedia, or your own analysis of its headers.  Those docs [claim that the GNU C library is compliant with ISO/IEC 9945-1:1996](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/POSIX.html), a.k.a. POSIX.1.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU C library is far from being just the standard C library.
Apart from ISO C, it implements several other standards (including several POSIX standards) as described in the [introduction part of its documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Standards-and-Portability).

The exact set of features you get from the glibc is controlled via [feature test macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Feature-Test-Macros).

See https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html for detailed documentation of the library.